# Trying to sort some placemarks from a kml file

Tags: java, android, sorting

As the title suggest I'm trying to sort some placemarks which I load from a kml file. I want them sorted by distance to the current location.

The problem is that my Placemarks aren't sorted as they are suppose to. When I look at them on a map I can see that they are clearly not sorted as they should be.

The relevant part of my Placemark class is shown below.

```
public class Placemark {
    ...

    public double distanceTo(double lat, double lon)
    {
      return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lat - this.lat, 2) + Math.pow(lon - this.lon, 2));
    }

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private double lat;
    private double lon;
}
```

I do the sorting in my PlacemarkLoader using PlacemarkComparator of which the relevant part is shown below.

```
@Override
public List<Placemark> loadInBackground() {
  List<Placemark> data = getPlacemarks(MainActivity.path);
  Collections.sort(data, new PlacemarkComparator(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
  return data;
}

private static class PlacemarkComparator implements Comparator<Placemark> {
  private double lat;
  private double lon;

  public PlacemarkComparator(double lat, double lon)
  {
      this.lat = lat;
      this.lon = lon;
  }

  @Override
  public int compare(final Placemark pm, final Placemark pm2) {
    if(pm.distanceTo(lat, lon) < pm2.distanceTo(lat, lon))
    {
      return -1;
    }
    else if(pm.distanceTo(lat, lon) > pm2.distanceTo(lat, lon))
    {
      return 1;
    }
    else
    {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions about where I go wrong? Please let me know if I should post more code or anything else.

Comment: Please expand on *aren't sorted as they are suppose to*. What is wrong with the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a propper WGS84 distance method:

```
public double distanceTo(double lat, double lon) {
  float[] result = new float[1];
  Location.distanceBetween(this.lat, this.lon, lat, lon, result);
  return result[0];
}
```

Or include it directly into your `Comperator`:

```
@Override
public int compare(final Placemark pm, final Placemark pm2) {
    float[] left = new float[1];
    float[] right = new float[1];

    Location.distanceBetween(this.lat, this.lon, pm.lat, pm.lon, left);
    Location.distanceBetween(this.lat, this.lon, pm2.lat, pm2.lon, right);

    return left[0] - right[0]; // or is it right[0] - left[0] ? :x
}
```

See official API documentation here:
[distanceBetween(double, double, double, double, float[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double, double, double, double, float[]))

Comment: Our code gave the same results which I found odd so I digged further and located the bug. Thanks for the support. I'll mark your answer as accepted and delete the entire question tomorrow. I believe that will give you the rep points... but I might be wrong :)